# Why the exception allowing same line opening brackets in class definitions?

Tags: php, coding-style, kohana

Here's an excerpt from the [Kohana conventions](http://kohanaframework.org/3.0/guide/kohana/conventions):

> Brackets are always on their own line. The exception to this rule is
>   the opening bracket for a class, which can be on the same line.

What could be the motivation behind the exception in question (the one that allows having an same line opening brackets in class definitions)?

Answer (score 1):

Throwing out a wild guess; to allow for "dummy" declarations intended to allow for overwriting/extension such as:

```
  class Route extends Kohana_Route {}
```

extending the declaration

```
  class Kohana_Route {
    // ...code...
  }
```

in a concise manner.

Answer (score 0):

This is only my guess but probably because an inline class bracket doesn't decrease readability of the code (usually only one at the beginning of the file).

Comment: There could be more than one in a file :?

Comment: But it's not that common (I wrote usually :))